# Java Glass pane

Tags: java, swing, awt, glasspane

I have a problem. I want to ask you how can I implement `GlassPane` to paint on it.

I mean, if I click mouse button, in `mouseClicked` event, my transparent glass pane should be created, because I want to see all my components behind `glassPane` and I can paint on it using `mouseDragged` event. When I release mouse button my `glassPane` disappears.

I have another question too. When I will paint on glass pane all my components behind them will be refreshing and repainting? Maybe somebody have nice example with glass pane which might help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html)

Comment: second link is very helpfull. Thx a lot

Comment: New address for the first link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html

Comment: Is there a new address for the second link as well? Unfortunately the code examples are not available anymore.